# JNI - Cannot load info library for OpenCV in Eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm working on a project about the introduction of human nature through handwriting analysis.

I use the JNI code in performing image preprocessing.
But when the program is run, I could not load library for OpenCV, program failed to load native code libraries from C + +.

Error : "CANNOT LOAD INFO LIBRARY FOR OPENCV"

But when I run one of the tutorial program OpenCV library, the library can load well.
What is wrong with my program?

This is my java code :

```
package com.example.cobanative;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String    TAG = null;

private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("modulNative");

            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(stringNative());
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_8, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

public native String stringNative();
}
```

This is my c++ code :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <string.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_cobanative_MainActivity_stringNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    jstring str = env->NewStringUTF("Hello from C++ over JNI");
    return str;
}
```

}

My Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include C:/Project/OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := modulNative
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Native.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And my Application.mk :

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

I'm sorry for my english. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Library is missing from the libs folder of your application.

Comment: @EricFortin How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just need to add **"OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED"** into your Android.MK, this should link opencv libraries into your c++ part:

```
...
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

include C:/Project/OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
...
```

This should work when you didn't broke OpenCV file structure since OpenCV.mk contains line:

```
OPENCV_LIBS_DIR:=$(OPENCV_THIS_DIR)/../libs/$(OPENCV_TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
```

that is heading to libs folder with all *.so (including libopencv_java.so which you probably missing)

Other thing that can "solve" the problem is adding **"OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on"** This will add libopencv_java.so into libs folder. But whole sample project is then about 15MB large and requires OpenCV Manager as well so this is not recommended.